# Format a range of cells as unlocked if another cell has a value of "x"

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a fairly large user input template and I would like to use some VBA code to format certain cells as "unlocked".

For example, if cell H9 = 5, then format cells M5:X5 as unlocked and have this code run all the way down the user input worksheet (will be about 2000 rows, run the code for each row).

Thank You
TM

Comment: I am able to get VBA to unlock the first row in my range but I cannot get the code to where it will move to the next row and repeat.  For example:
If H9=5 then unlock J9:X9. Then move to the next row down, if H10=5 the unlock J10:X10. Then move to the next row down and repeat, etc through row 2000

Answer (score 0):

For a single row:

```
Sub UnLockIt()
    If Range("H9").Value = 5 Then
        Range("H5:M5").Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

for 2000 rows

```
Sub UnLockIt()
    If Range("H9").Value = 5 Then
        Range("H5:M2004").Locked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Modify the 2004 to suit your needs.  This assumes that **Protection** has already been removed from the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student

Comment: Now, I need to apply this row by row all the way down the sheet. So is there something that will do this:
If H9=5 then unlock J9:X9.
Then move to the next row down, if H10=5 the unlock J10:X10.
Then move to the next row down and repeat, etc through row 2000

Answer (score 0):

I would add this to a `Worksheet Event`

1. right click your sheet tab
2. *View .... Code*
3. Copy and paste in the code below

Changing cells `H5:H10` will run the code on `M5:X10` etc

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, Range("H:H"))
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

For Each rng2 In rng1
     Cells(rng2.Row, 13).Resize(1, 12).Locked = False
Next rng2

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```